# "Explorer View" is missing from the drop down meun

Tags: explorer-view

I opened a sharepoint site. But I find that I can't choose the "Explorer View", only "All Documents", "Modify this View", "Create View", "Configure Views for This Location" menus displayed.

How can I configure to see the "Explorer View" ?

Answer (score 3):

Explorer View doesnt exist in 2010 appart from when you have the library tab.

http://techtrainingnotes.blogspot.co.uk/2010/05/sharepoint-2010-windows-explorer-view.html

and this:

> Explorer view
>
> Removed in SharePoint Foundation 2010. Libraries that have been
>   upgraded from earlier versions of SharePoint Foundation 2010 may still
>   have Explorer views and these may not work.

from:
[How do I enable "Open in Explorer"?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/27319/how-do-i-enable-open-in-explorer)

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are trying to see a view for a Document Library (from the 'All Documents' you specified). Is this for 2010 or 2007? If its 2010, You have to choose the option "Open with Explorer" in the ribbon.

Comment: I am using sharepoint 2010. Does "Open with Explorer" in the ribbon is the only way?

Comment: Yes, for viewing in Explorer View. Are you trying to achieve something else?

Answer (score -2):

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2423797

Comment: While  this may theoretically answer the question, we prefer inclusion of the  essential parts of the answer here, and to provide the link for  reference. See [answer](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-answer) for general guidelines. Please expand your answer and accept it (or one of the other answers). Thanks.