# Open in explorer not working, Internet Explorer 11

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-online, office-365

I have downloaded the hotfix,  but it is still not working. how do I know if I am opening the correct IE?

I need to be able to open in explorer view and have searched many different ways on the net about how to do so and no one has given me a solution to fix this issue.  Can anyone help?!

Comment: Have you downloaded the hotfix for IE? What is the version of IE and SharePoint you using?

Comment: As far as I am aware yes, but I could be wrong.  I'm using Internet Explorer 11 and not sure what version of SharePoint I am using.

Comment: I mean what is the edition of SharePoint... 2010 or 2013 you using?

Comment: We use the Online Microsoft Office SharePoint 2013

Comment: Any specific error you encountered while opening SharePoint list in Windows Explorer? If yes please post it.

Comment: The only error I have is when I try to open in Explorer View it tells me that the control is currently disabled. Every where I have read has said that there is a way round it, but I can't seem to figure out how.

Comment: check this one for troubleshooting http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2629108 it is better if you add more description / pictures of error, so that we undestand what's going on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the error is "The Control is currently disabled", that means the button is grey out and you cannot click it.

1. Make sure the SharePoint site is added inside trusted sites zone.
2. Make sure the ActiveX Control is enabled in Internet Explorer.

   2.1 Select Tools --> Internet Options menu from the Internet Explorer.

   2.2 Select the Security tab from the Internet Options dialog.

   2.3 Select Local Intranet Web content zone and click Custom Level.

   2.4 Make the following options available under ActiveX controls and plug-ins is Enabled.
3. Make sure your Internet Explorer version should be 32-bit.

   3.1 In IE click Help from the top menu bar.

   3.2 Click About Internet Explorer and check the version.

If its mentioned 256 bit then you have a 32 Bit IE installed, if its mentioned 64 bit then you have a 64 bit IE installed.

Comment: It is in the trusted site zone.
How do I check the ActiveX Control and the 32-bit?

Comment: I have edited my answer, you may check now.

Comment: It says my version is : 11.0.9600.17239

Comment: does IE-11 comes up with 32 bit version? Earlier we had IE 9 in our organization,  "Open in Explorer" used to work on 32bit version,  however recently we upgraded to IE11 and i do not see an option of IE11 32 bit.

Answer (score 1):

Responding to the question: **Open in explorer not working, Internet Explorer 11**

Answer:
Tools > Safety > ActiveX Filtering

Attempt to view SharePoint Files in Explorer view....worked for me ...hope it works for you

Answer (score 0):

The problem could be with IE11 Edge mode. If you open Developer Tools > Emulation > Document mode > 10 it might help.
From developer's prospective there should be a tag  in the head of the page to force IE use 10 document mode. This tag exists in OOTB sharepoint master pages...

Answer (score -1):

Follow the below steps:

1. Start the Windows Server Manager.
2. In the tree view, highlight the Features node.
3. In the details pane, click Add Features.
4. In the Add Features Wizard, check the Desktop Experience box, and then click Next.
5. Click Install.
6. When the Add Features Wizard has finished, click Close.
7. Click Yes when promoted to restart the computer.

Comment: How do I find Windows Server Manager?

Comment: Start->Administrative Tools->Server Manager

Comment: I don't have Server Manager listed

Comment: Are you using windows 7?

Comment: Yeah, but another company set the computer up

Comment: It says on my account I am the Administrator though

Comment: The solution which i gave is for windows server 2008 r2. For windows 7 please check whether WebClient Service is running and set it as automatic Startup Type. Let me know if it works

Comment: It is set up as automatic start up type and it is running and still cant open with Explorer.

Comment: what is the error you getting, it works at my end.

Comment: It tells me that the control is currently disabled

Comment: refer the link: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/27319/how-do-i-enable-open-in-explorer                                            if it doesn't work may be there must some configuration issue of sharepoint online version problem.

Comment: Also another solution you can check revert IE to IE10 or IE9 version to check whether it is a browser problem of IE one. just to confirm

Comment: I have read over that. I think I have the wrong internet explorer.

Comment: yes. may be something wrong in there. try switching IE.

Comment: Just now I'm in the process of deleting IE 11. Going to try IE 9

Comment: let me also know if it works.

Comment: I am giving up for today. Internet Explorer won't work any more! Will have another go tomorrow, if not will just leave it!