# Why does the 'Edit List' button sometimes open SharePoint Designer 2013 and sometimes navigate to Microsoft Download Centre?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, list, sharepoint-server

When clicking the 'Edit List' button on a SharePoint list from Internet Explorer:
[image: Visual of 'Edit List' button]

This sometimes opens SharePoint Designer 2013 and sometimes send me to the Microsoft [download link](http://www.microsoft.com/en-GB/download/details.aspx?id=35491) for SharePoint Designer 2013. This seems a list-specific behavior. A particularly frustrating one!

What is causing this?

Comment: From which browser?

Comment: Sorry - just edited the question to include this. IE.

Comment: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/114515/21421